Does 書道 actually mean "calligraphy" in the conventional sense of the word? Or does it imply something different?
In English, when I heard "calligraphy", I think of pretty/cleanly/elegantly written letters.
For the longest time, I thought 書道{しょどう} was a similar thing where, with ink and brush, you aim to write letters very nicely/cleanly, or prettily in a stylized manner.
But watching a show heavily featuring 書道, the examples of it look horribly ugly and unreadable, like a 4-yo playing trying to write with their left-hand. For example, here's an example of award-winning 書道 given in the show:

And here's an example of an average highschooler writing some using ink and brush (which isn't considered to be special)

And here's an example of an accomplished 書道の先生 writing the same thing, which is supposed to be more amazing

But am I insane, or does the highschooler's version look so much nicer/cleaner/elegant, whereas the 書道 expert's looks like an unreadable and rough mess that someone might've written with their left hand?
This led me to the line of thought: is 書道 not exactly what Americans might think of when they hear "calligraphy"? Is it more akin to graffiti/word art, where the point is to make highly artistic and creative portrayals of letters?


Do you do calligraphy? There are multiple styles, and not all of them are about making the letters as clear and readable as possible. Cursive styles particularly allow a writer to put more expression, feeling and nuance into their writing, and that's what you're seeing here.

Yeah, you seem to have a narrow image of the English word. If calligraphy is "the art of giving form to signs in an expressive, harmonious, and skillful manner" it stands to reason that there will be a variety of ways in which people do that and they won't all look similar.

@chausies Could you conceive of a set of aesthetics where energy and vitality, which sometimes might well trade off against legibility and clarity, could be valued?

I think this is an aesthetics question, not a linguistics question, making it off topic here.

Just as Western calligraphy has multiple styles, Japanese/Chinese 書道 also has various established styles. Notably, just as block letters and cursive script in English look entirely different, kanji also have cursive styles known as 行書 and 草書. While texts in 行書/草書 might appear messy or unreadable to the untrained eye, they actually follow relatively established rules and are seen as beautiful by those familiar with them. The 推し疲れ example from that sensei seems to be a good example of traditional and beautiful 行書 to me, and it's suitable for students to trace and practice. Generally, Japanese students start from "block" style (楷書) in elementary school, and some students learn 行書 in middle school. Very few people learn how to read/write 草書 today, which means a good portion of 書道 works are hardly readable even to average native Japanese speakers.
On the other hand, 書道 is also a creative art form. There are cases where highly stylized, freely transformed characters are still regarded as 書道 and appreciated as artwork. Such works may indeed bear some resemblance to Western graffiti. Even so, such creative 書道 is based on the deep knowledge of 行書/草書, so simply writing random squiggly characters will never be appreciated as beautiful. Great 書道 artists engage in creative 書道 as they seek to go beyond the traditional forms, but they can naturally write beautiful 楷書/行書/草書, too.

yes, it's like sword art- once you trained hard enough to become a master, you can express your own styles with either a sword or a pen.
Art is something very abstractive, one can say it's ugly and other could say it's a masterpiece.
